# A solution works faster than a for loop

Tags: python, linux, grep

I have a directory contained 1.5 M text files with the following content:

```
TDB_TCFE9:
POLY version  3.32
POLY:POLY:POLY:POLY:POLY: Using global minimization procedure
Calculated         71400 grid points in             1 s
Found the set of lowest grid points in              1 s
 Calculated POLY solution      11 s, total time    13  s
POLY: VPV(LIQUID)=0
POLY:POLY:POLY:POLY:POLY:POLY: Using global minimization procedure
Calculated         71400 grid points in             1 s
Found the set of lowest grid points in              0 s
 Calculated POLY solution       5 s, total time     6  s
POLY: *** STATUS FOR ALL PHASES
```

The files is named like `id1.TCM.log`. Only the number after `id`changes.

What I want to do is grep the value after `VPV(LIQUID)=` and give this value to `x1` and then `x2`. 
if `x2` is larger than 0.0001, then move the corresponding file to the directory `with_liquid`. If not, do nothing.

The code I use is

```
for j in `seq 1500000`
do
echo ${j}
  x1=`grep -a VPV\(LIQUID\) id${j}.TCM.log |sed s/POLY_3://g|awk 'BEGIN{FS="="}{print $2}'|tail -1`
    x2=$(printf "%.14f" $x1)
    if [ $(echo "$x2 > 0.0001"| bc -l)  -eq 1 ]; then
    mv id${j}.TCM.log with_liquid
    fi
done
```

It works good. The only problem is taking too long time. How can I do much faster? I am also open to a python code or any other solution.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Have you considered multiprocessing to take advantage of all of your CPU cores?

Comment: @Chris I am open to it and do not know how to do it.

Comment: Is each file only about as big as the example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A first pass at just improving the performance of the script you have:

```sh
for file in id{0..1500000}.TCM.log; do  # Use a brace expansion
                                        # instead of the subshell to seq
    printf 'Processing %s\n' "$file"
    x1=$(grep -o 'VPV(LIQUID)=\d*\.\?\d*' "$file")  # VPV(LIQUID)=0.0 or the like
    printf -v x2 '%.14f' "${x1#*=}"  # Parameter expansion to strip the part before the =
    bc -l <<< "$x2 > 0.0001" ||  # Use the exit status value directly
        mv "$file" with_liquid/
done
```

Given how many files you have here, how you implement this is important, but not as important as parallelizing it. A simple way to do that is to use tools like `xargs` with the -P flag. A more powerful implementation is [GNU Parallel](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/). Suppose you define the middle part of the script (everything inside the `for` loop, with `file` renamed as `$1`) in an executable file called `xsplit`.

```
printf '%s\n' id{0..1500000}.TCM.log | xargs -P 50 ./xsplit
```

You will want to tune `maxprocs` carefully for your purposes -- it's the maximum number of processes xargs will spawn. I chose 50 arbitrarily here.

Another consideration is that, based on the example file you gave, these files are each very small -- less than 600 bytes. So the entire set of 1.5M files is under one GB -- you can load all of that into memory at once on commodity hardware. That boils the entire script down to

```
[[ $(<file) =~ VPV\(LIQUID\)=([[:digit:]]\.?[[:digit:]]*) ]] &&
    bc -l <<< "${BASH_REMATCH[1]} > 0.0001" ||
    mv "$file" with_liquid/
```

Comment: I got a error message like this when I script above ```Processing id212.TCM.log
./del_liq_new.sh: line 7: printf: `%.14f': not a valid identifier
^C(standard_in) 1: syntax error```

Comment: Sorry about that, it was a typo. I fixed it. It should've been `printf -v x1 ...`

Comment: you mean do it like this```for file in id{0..1500000}.TCM.log; do [[ $(<file) =~ VPV\(LIQUID\)=([[:digit:]]\.?[[:digit:]]*) ]] &&
    bc -l <<< "${BASH_REMATCH[1]} > 0.0001" ||
    mv "$file" with_liquid/; done```

Answer (score 2):

The primary reason why your code is slow is that it requires about nine forks per file.

It will be dramatically much faster if you don't fork:

```
awk -F= '/VPV\(LIQUID\)/ && $2 > 0.0001 { print FILENAME }' id*.TCM.log |
    xargs mv -t with_liquid
```

Comment: Parallelize that xargs and you're even more golden.

Comment: Nice answer. You may get a fraction more performance if you use `gawk` and `nextfile` after the `print` so you don't bother searching the remainder of the lines after `VPV(LIQUID)`. And possibly even a fraction more if you anchored your search at the start of the line.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a possible Python implementation. The choice is between using lightweight threads, which are suitable for I/O bound jobs vs. using processes, which can handle CPU intensive operations better. Currently the code for using processes has been commented out with #. You should try both and see what works better. Also play around the number of threads (the number of processes should not be greater than the number of processors you actually have).

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
#from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor
import re, glob, os

NUMBER_OF_THREADS = 20
NUMBER_OF_PROCESSES = 5

x1_regex = re.compile(r'VPV\(LIQUID\)=(\d+(?:\.\d*)?|\.\d+)')

def process_file(i):
    fn = f'id{i}.TCM.log'
    try:
        with open(fn) as f:
            text = f.read()
        m = x1_regex.search(text)
        if m:
            x1 = float(m[1])
            if x1 > .0001:
                os.rename(fn, f'with_liquid/{fn}')
        return None # no error
    except Exception as e:
        return (e, fn)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=NUMBER_OF_THREADS) as executor:
    #with ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=NUMBER_OF_PROCESSES) as executor:
        for result in executor.map(process_file, range(150001)):
            if result:
                print(f'Exception {result[0]} processing file {result[1]}.')
```

Comment: @MarkSetchell Just unlucky, I guess.

Comment: I meant it should not be possible to answer a question that has been closed for an hour.